# Ruby Group regular expression to match only first occurence

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract a specific pattern from a string using a regular expression group. My pattern is

```
'*-to:' 'anything as a text but not an email' 'email'
```

eg.

```
send-to: Firstname Surname something@email.com
```

I am using

```
/(^.*-to:)(.*[^*@*])(\s[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})/i
```

which works fine when the exact pattern is matched but if I get

```
send-to: Firstname Surname something@email.com somethingelse@email.com
```

it returns both mails which is not the desirable result. How I could get only the exact matches of this specific pattern?

Comment: Replace `.*` with `.*?`.

Comment: A good way to debug your regex is using regex101. https://regex101.com/r/aZDhJe/1 shows that your second test case isn't behaving as you would expect. https://regex101.com/r/aZDhJe/2 shows it working as you indicate is desired.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it’s worth to mention that capturing emails with a regexp is a bad idea and that tld might be longer than 4 symbols nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for this @WiktorStribiżew . It works now.